# Failed to ping windows VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping

I'm trying to get my Local PC to join my VM win server 2016,

I have managed to set up the domain controller on the server and got no issues with that.

I tried to ping the VM from my device and got request time out, meanwhile pinging my device from the server succeeded with 0% loss.

Network adapter on the server is set to NAT, I have added port forwarding (host and guest port set 80). file and printer sharing was all set to on.

I tried to play with it and changed it to bridge adapter and switched off the firewall also failed.

The IP address on the server set to 10.0.2.15 by default.

Any advise on how can I manage to establish the connection between my device and the server?

Why?

I'm trying to learn about power-shell scripting and the plan is to join my computer to the domain and try to practice some staff about remoting "PSremoting" and I'm facing issues with that since my device is not on the same domain as the VM.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Set your VM to Bridged Networking for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your trying to join the host machine to a domain server running on a VM running on the same machine?  You are going to have problems doing that.

Comment: The other way to experiment with this is to make your Host Machine Server 2016 and then make your guest machines as workstation machines. That will work much better.

Comment: @Ramhound no, not really. Its not uncommon for the host to be joined on the guest DC. Some consider it best practice even.

Comment: @John I have tried that but it didn't work

Comment: @Ramhound that's exactly what I'm trying. really ? do you have any suggestions ? do you think if I do that on 2 VMs would work ?

Comment: Consider my suggestion of using the Host for you Server.